# IntelliJ - After adding dependency jar, How do I use the methods in the Jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I am looking to create an external library of some methods being used in one of my classes. I moved those methods into their own project and created a jar file of that project. I then added that jar file to the dependencies of my original project so it appears in the external libraries section of my project. I also tried adding it as a library (which is why it appears twice in the picture). However I am not able to call any of the methods that exist within the jar file. I can't seem to import the file either. Please help.

[My code where I am trying to use methods found in SortLibrary.jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEbq2.png)

**Edit:** I have tried many variations of `import SortLibrary`, `import Sortlibrary.jar`, etc - all to no avail.

**Edit 2: SOLVED:** my jar needed to not use a default package

Comment: My guess would be that you have to refer to the class housing those functions.

Comment: I've tried calling things like SortLibrary.function() which is still unrecognized

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebuilding your project? Some times the project can not find the jars without rebuilding or cleaning the project.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to:

- add the `import` statement with the full class name, eg: `import my.package.SortLibrary;`. In this case you should be able to use your methods with a class reference, like this: `SortLibrary.prompt("File name?");`
- if you don't want a class reference, use `static` import: `import static my.package.SortLibrary.prompt;` (or `import static my.package.SortLibrary.*` to import all static methods)

By the way, in the IntelliJ IDEA, if you point your cursor on the method you need to import and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will suggest you to import it automatically.

**NOTE:** You can not import the `SortLibrary` if it belongs to the *unnamed package* (has no package declaration). See [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5).

Comment: I've doing things like Import SortLibrary and it isn't recognized. Additionally, alt + enter doesnt reveal any suggestions as to what to import over the red methods.

Comment: @Christopher how did you package that jar? Why doesn't your `SortingLibrary` class belong to any package inside the jar?

Comment: @Christopher note that if your `SortingLibrary` has no package specified (aka default package), then you can not access it from any other packages.

Comment: I believe SortingLibrary has no package, Ill look it changing it, thank you

Comment: @Christopher I think this is the reason. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Christopher if this solved your problem, please accept the answer so that people know that the issue is resolved